# Select only one row matching distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how to query this structure:
How can I

```
SELECT only 1 ID FROM portfolio 
WHERE category = "x" AND DISTINCT description = 'x'?
```

(Table name and fields)

```
portfolio:
ID, client, section, category, description, year, files
```

EDIT: Thank you for the answers.

Comment: Which row that matches the criteria you specify do you want?

Comment: Please specify your tried query and error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID from portfolio WHERE category = 'x' AND description = 'x' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM profolio
WHERE category = 'x' AND description = 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit statement in mysql like below.

```
select id from portfolio where category='x' and description='x' limit 1 offset 0
```